# Database context and Return Dynamic Result Set in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 and EF 5 i want to run dynamic query.

```
var returndata = Context.Database.SqlQuery(Type, strsql, null);
```

i don't know, how many fields it will return and name. Out of this result i want to make table structure that will display on view.

Question : What should i passed as Type?

my query return below result:

Field 1, Field 2, Field 3, Field 4, Field 5

Row1...

Row2..

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: In what situation are you executing a query without knowing the expected results?  It sounds like an invitation for SQL injection, and on the surface seems like this should be avoided.

Comment: @Jason, you can consider Pivot query over here.

Comment: @Jason, one example would be using a stored procedure where the result set could change. E.g. Reporting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72580835/861716

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i made is using TypeBuilder option suggested by "Mortalus" and ExpandoObject object. It has little performance overhead right now.

Take Typebuilder code from "Mortalus" answer then i made code according to my requirement as below.

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> expandolist = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var item in returndata)
  {
  IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
  foreach (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item))
     {
      var obj = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(item);
      expando.Add(propertyDescriptor.Name, obj);
     }
     expandolist.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>(expando));
  }

  return expandolist;
```

so now, I have "Dictionary" object from dynamic object. and using it you can work easily at design time rather then wait until runtime using "dynamic" object.

Comment: how did you retrieve returnData? `Context.Database.SqlQuery(Type, sqlStatement, null);` - Type == ? thanks

Comment: my return type was List<Dictionary<string, object>>. In SqlQuery return type it will make it dynamic using TypeBuilder.

Comment: Please see below answer of Mortalus for how to use TypeBuilder.

Answer (score 25):

You could use a raw SQL query because EF doesn't support that:

```
private static IEnumerable<object[]> Read(DbDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var values = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            values.Add(reader.GetValue(i));
        }
        yield return values.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var ctx = new UsersContext())
    using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var model = Read(reader).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<object[]>
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var column in row)
                {
                    <td>@column</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this way before but i was getting error like below, i tried with String[]. {"The result type 'System.Object[]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor."}

Comment: @Dips, I have updated my answer with an example of a raw query you could use.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i think i will go with Mortalus's answer below, in that i have to do little more work to know my fields ahead of time before making Type.

Comment: Sure, just be careful with the additional performance overhead price you will have to pay by using reflection. This approach is very expensive as it is emitting types dynamically at runtime. It is even slower compared to using reflection.

Comment: I have tried using this solution, but it has a drawback for me. I am using it inside a transactionscope, inside which I perform EF queries aswell. The call to ctx.Database.Connection.Open() means that 2 SqlConnections are open at once inside a transactionscope, which in turn escalates the transaction to DTC. I want to avoid that. Is there no way to do this using EF? Or can the reader use the same SqlConnection as the EF?

Comment: DbDataReader  does not exist in this project. Please share reference @DarinDimitrov

Answer (score 11):

This method loads data from SQL select (with parameters) to the list of rows, where each row is the dictionary of columns (the key is the column name).

```
private static List<Dictionary<string, object>> LoadData(string sqlSelect, params object[] sqlParameters)
{
    var table = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    using (var ctx = new DbEntities())
    {
        ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
        using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sqlSelect;
            foreach (var param in sqlParameters)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        row[reader.GetName(i)] = reader[i];
                    table.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently stumbled upon this example:

[http://www.markzhou.com/blog/post/2011/06/02/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-41-SqlQuery()-method.aspx](http://www.markzhou.com/blog/post/2011/06/02/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-41-SqlQuery%28%29-method.aspx)

I haven't had the time to test it myself but it seems that it is possible with some additional work to construct the dynamic type.

In short you would want to do something like this:

```
  TypeBuilder builder = Program.CreateTypeBuilder(
                "MyDynamicAssembly", "MyModule", "MyType");
  Program.CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, "name", typeof(string));
  Program.CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, "type", typeof(string));
  Program.CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, "id", typeof(int));

  Type resultType = builder.CreateType();
  dynamic queryResult = context.Database.SqlQuery(
                    resultType, "SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects");
```

Where `TypeBuilder` is described in details in the post I have attached.

Comment: Thanks Mortalus, i also came through article before. I have one issue over here that i should have known my field "name" here. in my case i am making my query dynamically with all fields just like in pivot.

Comment: Then you'r back to square one :).. probably Darin Dimitrov solution will suites you best as you have to go back to basics with the raw data set object.

Comment: I am thinking same way, because after implementing this solution i had issue on how to display this dynamic type on View. i couldn't figured it out.

Comment: finally i made working using TypeBuilder and ExpandoObject. so at the view end i can get name of this dynamic properties with Value.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the type that is returned, I think you might be out of luck.

If you know what patterns it might fall under, you could use some `try { } catch () { }`'s on interfaces that match those parameters on your otherwise dynamic query, but that seems like it might be a bit painful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, EF won't materialize objects unless it knows their `Type`.

If this is really necessary for you, I think your best bet would be to fall back to `ADO.NET` and `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly post by Darin Dimitrov, but it returns DataTable

```
public DataTable QueryToTable(Entities db, string queryText, SqlParameter[] parametes)
        {
            using ( DbDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = queryText;
                if (parametes != null)
                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parametes);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                return table;
            }
        }
```

Use

```
SqlParameter[] parametes = new[]
                {
                    new SqlParameter("date_from", dateFrom)
                };

DataTable tab = QueryToTable(new Entities(), 
               "Select *  From SomeTable Where ADate >= @date_from", parametes);
```

Example for MS SQL Server

Comment: I am working with web api and wasted 4 hours to find this solution. Thanks It solves my Problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Petr Voborník's answer, dynamic query, I add dynamic insert of ResultSet, my application takes the dynamic query of all tables of the entire database, a chunk at a time and then inserts the dynamic results into a remote database, using Always Encrypted (omitted here). Passing a sb command and parameter object.

```
    public void StoreData(DbContext dbContext, Dictionary<string, string> columnInfo, List<Dictionary<string, object>> multiInsertObj, string tableName)
    {
        _ctx = dbContext;
        _columnInfo = columnInfo;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(BuildSqlCommand(tableName, columnInfo, multiInsertObj.Count));
        ExecuteSqlCommand(sb, GetParamsObject(columnInfo, multiInsertObj));
    }

    private static StringBuilder BuildSqlCommand(string tableName, Dictionary<string, string> variableInfo, int variableCount)
    {
        //Build sql command
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("INSERT INTO dbo." + tableName + "(");
        foreach (var variable in variableInfo)
        {
            sb.Append(variable.Key);
            sb.Append(", ");
        }
        sb.Append("SystemNumber, ");
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2).Append(") VALUES ");
        for (var i = 0; i < variableCount; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("(");
            foreach (var name in variableInfo.Keys)
            {
                sb.Append("@" + name + "_" + i + ",");
            }
            sb.Append("@SystemNumber" + "_" + i + ",");
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).Append("),");
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
        return sb;
    }

    private static object[] GetParamsObject(Dictionary<string, string> columnInfo, List<Dictionary<string, object>> multiInsertObj)
    {
        var variableCount = multiInsertObj.Count;
        var rowCount = multiInsertObj[0].Keys.Count;
        var objectLength = (rowCount + 1) * variableCount;
        var variableDataTypes = columnInfo.Values.ToList();
        var paramObj = new object[objectLength];
        var j = 0;
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var row in multiInsertObj)
        {
            var k = 0;
            foreach (var data in row)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("@");
                sb.Append(data.Key);
                sb.Append("_" + i);
                paramObj[j] = new SqlParameter(sb.ToString(), SetSqlDataType(variableDataTypes[k])) { Direction = Input, Value = data.Value };
                j++;
                k++;
            }
            paramObj[j] = new SqlParameter(("@SystemNumber" + "_" + i), SetSqlDataType("int")) { Direction = Input, Value = _systemNumber };
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        return paramObj;
    }

    private static void ExecuteSqlCommand(StringBuilder sb, params object[] sqlParameters)
    {
        using (_ctx)
        {
            _ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
            using (var cmd = _ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
                foreach (var param in sqlParameters)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These approaches seemed a bit complicated to me, at least in my situation. All I needed was to return a DataTable so it could be previewed. Meaning every value could be a string.

So I created two classes:

```
public class DynamicResultModel
{
    public DynamicResultColumnModel headers = new();
    public List<DynamicResultColumnModel> rows = new();
}
public class DynamicResultColumnModel
{
    public List<string> columns = new();
}
```

Then created a simple helper class to basically serialize and deserialize a DataTable into and out of a DynamicResultModel

```
public static DynamicResultModel DataTableToDynamic(DataTable dtData)
{
    DynamicResultModel result = new();
    DynamicResultColumnModel headers = new();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dtData.Columns)
    {
        result.headers.columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dtData.Rows)
    {
        DynamicResultColumnModel rowData = new();
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            rowData.columns.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        result.rows.Add(rowData);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The only caveat was that I could not return a `DynamicResultModel` from my controller, I had to serialize it into a string first. Regardless, this worked for me and saved me a lot of time.

So my API endpoint definition was

```
Task<ApiResponse<string>>
```

Instead of

```
Task<ApiResponse<DynamicResponseModel>>
```